# Question on equivalence classes on linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, matrix-rank

Q.

On the set M of all $m * n$ real matrices, introduce the following equivalence relation: two such
matrices A and B are equivalent if there exist a real invertible $m * m$ matrix P and a real invertible
$n * n$ matrix Q such that A = PBQ. Into how many disjoint equivalence classes is M partitioned
by this equivalence relation?

I think

To determine the number of disjoint equivalence classes, we need to find how many different equivalence classes exist in M.

Consider the matrix A .The matrix A can be decomposed as $A = P_1DQ_1$, where $P_1$ is an invertible matrix, D is a diagonal matrix with diagonal elements λ1, λ2, ..., λr, where r is the rank of A, and $Q_1$ is an invertible  matrix.

Similarly, any matrix B in M can be decomposed as $B = P_2DQ_2$, where $P_2$ is an invertible  matrix, D is a diagonal matrix with diagonal elements μ1, μ2, ..., μs, where s is the rank of B, and $Q_2$ is an invertible matrix.

If A and B are equivalent, then there exist invertible matrices P and Q such that A = PBQ. Substituting the expressions for A and B, we get $P_1DQ_1$ = $PBPQ_2$. Since $P_1$ and $P_2$ are invertible, we can left-multiply both sides by $P_2^-1$ and right-multiply by $Q_1^-1$ to get $D = P_2^-1BPQ_1^-1.$

Thus, two matrices A and B are equivalent if and only if they have the same rank and the diagonal entries of the diagonal matrices D in their respective decompositions are equal up to permutation.

Therefore, the number of disjoint equivalence classes in M is equal to the number of different sets of diagonal entries of rank r matrices, where r ranges from 0 to min(m, n).

Am i in right way or anything mistake.. please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This equivalence relation is actually called "[matrix equivalence.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_equivalence)" Two matrices of the same dimensions are equivalent if and only if they have the same rank (no other condition is required), so for the set of $\ m\times n\ $ real matrices, there are $\ \min(m,n)+1\ $ equivalence classes, corresponding to each of the possible ranks $\ 0,1,2,\dots,\min(m,n)\ $.